# Error deploying react-scripts application to GAE

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, reactjs, react-scripts

I'm attempting to deploy a newly generated react-scripts based application to GAE and am running into an issue.  It appears as though the build completes successfully but it fails during deploy/'Updating service'.  Looking for some pointers on how to debug what's happening as I don't see anything in the error log in the console.

Below is the output from the last part of the build:

```
Step 5 : CMD npm start
 ---> Running in b930fc7e35e6
 ---> 2d0d24685054
Removing intermediate container b930fc7e35e6
Successfully built 2d0d24685054
```

Below is the error I am seeing during the service update:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "venue-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy --project venue-web"
  }
}
```

Comment: rollback to previous successful deploy config and apply your changes incrementally to reveal the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing react-scripts in your dependencies.